# Virtualbox on Ubuntu 12.04 and 3.5 kernel compilation problem

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, virtualbox, compiling

I have installed the 3.5 kernel under Ubuntu 12.04.  When I install virtualbox I recieve the following error.

```
Setting up virtualbox (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                      
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                                   [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.5.0-18-generic
Building initial module for 3.5.0-18-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                      
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                                                   [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to resolve this?

**Edit** -- Here is the make.log

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.1.12 for kernel 3.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Mon Nov 19 12:12:23 EST 2012
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjLinuxDoMmap’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1150:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_mmap’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10709) in VirtualBox: additions will not compile with 3.5 kernels. You will need to update VirtualBox to, at least, version 4.1.20, where it's solved.

Some people in the VB forums reported success running 4.1.20 additions on 4.1.18 VirtualBox, but it looks quite a risky and untested idea to me.

Comment: I ended up pulling down the latest version from their site instead of using the apt repo version.  The latest version worked without issue.

Comment: There is also a bug open in Launchpad [#1127101](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1127101)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:debfx/virtualbox &&\
sudo apt-get update &&\
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

That solved the problem for me.